# How to get data of radio button and checkbox in frontend form?

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend

I have one form in frontend. In that i have so many radio button and checkbox.

Now when i edit that form that time i want set data of radio button and checkbox.

my phtml

```
<div id="edit_fri">
        <li><?php echo $this->__("FRI");?> </li>
        <li><input class="allday" type="checkbox" name="availableday[Friday][9-12]" value="9AM - 12AM"></li>
        <li><input class="allday" type="checkbox" name="availableday[Friday][12-6]" value="12PM - 6PM"></li>
        <li><input class="allday" type="checkbox" name="availableday[Friday][6-9]" value="6PM - 9PM"></li>
</div>
<div id="edit_sat">
        <li><?php echo $this->__("SAT");?> </li>
        <li><input class="allday" type="checkbox" name="availableday[Saturday][9-12]" value="9AM - 12AM"></li>
        <li><input class="allday" type="checkbox" name="availableday[Saturday][12-6]" value="12PM - 6PM"></li>
        <li><input class="allday" type="checkbox" name="availableday[Saturday][6-9]" value="6PM - 9PM"></li>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <label class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Gender');?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="radio" id="male" class="validate-one-required" name="gender" value="0" >
                <label for="male">
                    <span class="m-selected-radio-button" title="male"><?php echo $this->__("Male");?></span>
                </label>
                <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="1" >
                    <label for="female">
                        <span class="m-selected-radio-button" title="female"><?php echo $this->__("Female");?></span>
                    </label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In radion button save value like 0 or 1,but in checkbox i save string like this

```
{"Friday":{"12-6":"12PM - 6PM","6-9":"6PM - 9PM"},"Saturday":{"12-6":"12PM - 6PM","6-9":"6PM - 9PM"}}
```

so how to get selected  radio button and checkbox

Comment: So how do you want it to be saved?

Comment: It not about save data. i want to get data when i am edit this form

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean

Comment: In above using that code make a one form and save data to database. when i am edit that form that time i want to get selected radio and checkbox. understand or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume when you edit the form you have an array that contains the data you want to edit. Let's call that array `$data`.
You can check if the checkbox with the name `availableday[Friday][9-12]` should be checked like this:

```
if (isset($data['Friday']['9-12']) && $data['Friday']['9-12'] == '9AM - 12AM') {
    $checked = ' "checked"="checked"';
} else {
    $checked = "";
}
```

Then make the input look like this:

```
<li><input class="allday" type="checkbox" name="availableday[Friday][9-12]" value="9AM - 12AM"<?php echo $checked;?>></li>
```

You should do the same for all the other checkboxes.

for radio do the same but check `if ($data['gender'] == 1)` or `0`

Comment: your solution is working but its to much broad because i have so many radio button and checkbox . Is it possible to another way which is not too broad